# Trying to reach my openfire server through my android client

Tags: android, xmpp, port, chat, openfire

I want to create my own XMPP android client . So I begane with the samsung tutorial which interface itself with gmail and that you can find here :
http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Building-a-Chat-Application

It worked like a charm. Now I tryed to setup  this client for working with my openfire server.

For this I converted the folowing lines:

```
public static final String HOST = "My public ip(82.65....)";
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "xmppclient.talkative.com";
public static final String USERNAME = "test";
public static final String PASSWORD = "test";
```

Actually we find back these variable in the connection setter:

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
```

Finally I never manage to connect to the server and I always get the following error

```
03-27 00:18:00.660: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(29942): Failed to connect to      81.65.**.***:5222.
03-27 00:18:00.663: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(29942): XMPPError connecting to 81.65.**.***:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to 81.65.**.***:5222.
```

This seems to be very simple but still I cannot get the right connection .

I precise that I have the good INTERNET conf in my Manifest.

If anyone has a clue it would be really usefull .

Thanks

Comment: try without service and then try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SERVICE - is the "Server name" of your openfire instance, it should be `talkative.com`.
- HOST - it is a public DNS name of the server machine, e.g. `xmppclient.talkative.com`
- PORT - 5222 in the default setup, check this port should be **open** to public network.

If you have access to DNS configuration of talkative.com, you can add SRV record 
`_xmpp-server._tcp.talkative.com` pointing to `xmppclient.talkative.com:5269` (if you want to add your server in federation with other public XMPP servers) and
`_xmpp-client._tcp.talkative.com` pointing to `xmppclient.talkative.com:5222`.
This is a perfect setup, in which case Smack ConnectionConfiguration requires only

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    "talkative.com");
```

And all other parameters it will detect automatically via DNS.

Answer (score 1):

just use two following parameters to connect from server

public static final String HOST = "192.168.1.124";

public static final int PORT =5222;

After this further process will start. Host will be the ipaddress of your system where you installed openfire server but condition is you must be in same network Ipaddress, port defautly be 5222.